Postgresql <-> Data Gateway <-> Power Apps
I have a table on a local postgresql.
I am using Data Gateway, which is up and running and it's connected successfully with Power Apps. When building a very simple Form to insert data into the table, I can access the fields from the table. So I guess, this connection is ok.
However, when I click my submit form which is basically:
SubmitForm(Form1)
I get the error:
network error when using patch function: the requested operation is invalid

Any ideas on what I could do to troubleshoot this?
EDIT:
I have created a test table with only 2 columns. The form has two fields and the submit form. The error is the same...
So could it be an issue with the connection with postgres???

Not sure but what I guess possible issues could be, you have not patched all mandatory fields.

I checked that the columns were not mandatory. It's really a simple table.

I found the solution. I don't know if this is the correct one but it works..
On my table on Postgresql I created a Primary Key named ID, with auto-increment.
Then I add the ID field on my Power app.

As the "Default" I put this:
If(Form1.Mode = FormMode.New, Last('database.my table').id + 1, ThisItem.id)
Which updates the ID automatically with the next ID.
Then, on my Save button, I used the PATCH function like this:
Patch('database.my_table', Defaults('database.my_table'), {id:Value(DataCardValue17.Text), other_column:(DataCardValue18.Text) });Navigate(another_form)
And it worked. When I click on save, the row is inserted, the ID is updated to the next and I get redirected to another page.
I hope this helps other people with the same issue.
If anyone has other solution, please let me know.

This is a known limitation on Postgresql connector:

Insert row operation requires to provide explicit value for Primary
Key column, even though default/autoincrement value is defined.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/postgresql/#known-issues-and-limitations for more details

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
